# Gerar arquivo txt com fonte das letras personalizada

Tags: c#, webforms, txt, font

Estou criando um código que gera um txt para imprimir numa impressora 
matricial. Porém, gostaria de alterar a fonte das letras. Alguém poderia
me ajudar, por favor?

Segue abaixo o código.

```
    try{

        byte[] bytes;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                string divisao = "=";
                for(int i = 0; i < 79; i++)
                {
                    divisao += "=";
                }
                foreach (eOA01 x in Lpdf)
                {                        
                    textWriter.WriteLine(divisao);
                    textWriter.WriteLine("ENDERECO= " + x.ENDERECO);
                    textWriter.WriteLine(x.PORTA);                      

                }

                textWriter.Flush();

                bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        Button3.Enabled = false;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=OS" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + ".txt");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.
        string err = ex.Message;
    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Arquivos `.txt` não suporta estilização, portanto, você não pode alterar tamanho, cor, estilo e família da fonte. Gere um PDF ou crie um arquivo .RTF.

Comment: Eu consigo alterar no  notepad. Mas via código então deve ser inviável.

Comment: É porque na verdade você altera as configurações de exibição de texto do Bloco de Notas em si e não do texto digitado/escrito. Para isso como CyberPotato disse use um arquivo RTF.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado!